# Recycling Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, powershell, internet-explorer

Is there anything I can do to this code to optimize it to use less resources?

```
write-host (get-date -format s) " Beginning script..."
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
do{
    $len = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens.Length;
    if($len-eq1){
        $ie = Get-Process -Name iexplore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($ie -ne $null){
            Write-Host (get-date -format s) "Stopping IE..."
            $ie | Stop-Process
        }
    }elseif($len-eq2){
        $ie = Get-Process -Name iexplore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($ie -eq $null){
            write-Host (get-date -format s) " Starting IE..."
            Start-Sleep -s 5 #5
            $ie = Open-InternetExplorer -Url http://localhost/ -Left 1366 -FullScreen -InForeground #This is an external function that works well.
            write-Host (get-date -format s) " IE Started"
        }
    }
    start-sleep -s 10
}while(1-eq1)
```

Comment: Can you give us a little more context about the script's purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You should have included `Open-InternetExplorer` - without it, this code is incomplete and does not run.

A few of optimizations...

- You will not need to `Add-Type` if all you need is the screen property. It might also make more sense to use `Count` rather than `Length`, afterall this code relies on the number of screens.
- Unless the number of screens changes per iteration of the loop, getting this value could be taken outside the loop. Otherwise, consider a `switch` and remove `$len` altogether:

  ```
  Switch ([System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens.Count) {
     1 {
        ...
     }
     2 {
        ...
     }
  }
  ```
- The condition for the infinite loop `while (1-eq1)` can be simplified to avoid having to calculate a result. Use `while ($true)` or `while (1)`.
- When IE is started, the script does not use the return value so it isn't necessary to assign it to `$ie`:

  ```
  $null = Open-InternetExplorer -Url http://...
  ```
- The use of `$ie`is actually unnecessary in both cases.

---

The resulting script could look like:

```
write-host (get-date -format s) " Beginning script..."
do {
   Switch ([System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens.Count) {
      1 {
         Get-Process -Name iexplore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -Force
         If ($?) {
            Write-Host (get-date -format s) "Stopping IE..."
         }
      }
      2 {
         if ((Get-Process -Name iexplore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null){
            write-Host (get-date -format s) " Starting IE..."
            Start-Sleep -s 5 #5
            $null = Open-InternetExplorer -Url http://localhost/ -Left 1366 -FullScreen -InForeground
            write-Host (get-date -format s) " IE Started"
         }
      }
   }
   start-sleep -s 10
} while(1)
```